# How to Show Table from google speadsheet after login (Google Web App)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

Everybody . I'm doing some mini web-app but I'm new in programming
,I followed tutorial from "Learn Google Spreadsheets" on Youtube but get a little bit confuse

My App is very simple
1.User login Page (Check Usercode and Pass from firebase) --- DONE!
2.Get data (get Usercode and find data row from spreadsheet) --- DONE!
3.Pass Object to Table --- Need help

```
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1l2Q7C5qBF7EsDInlHi1Bv76jeRJwWjixKteBkc8i3ik');
var PayrollSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ข้อมูลล่าสุด") ;
var Route = {} ;
Route.path = function(route,callback){
  Route[route] = callback ;
}

function doGet(e) {

  Route.path("Login",LoadLogin) ;
  Route.path("Table",LoadTable) ;

  if(Route[e.parameters.v]){
      return Route[e.parameters.v]() ;

  }else {
      return render("Login") ;
 }

}

function LoadLogin(){

  return  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Login').evaluate() ;

}

function LoadTable(Usercode){

var TargetRow = GetRow(Usercode) ;
var Data  =    PayrollSheet.getRange(TargetRow,1,1,18).getValues().flat();
var Round =   PayrollSheet.getRange(1,2,1,2).getValues().flat();


return render("Table",{array:Data,round:Round}) ;

}

function render(file,argsObject){

var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
if(argsObject){
  var keys = Object.keys(argsObject) ;

      keys.forEach(function(key){
  
          tmp[key]   = argsObject[key] ;

        });

      } // END IF
   return    tmp.evaluate() ;
}
```

Javascript in html file

```
    <script>

function LoginUser() {
   
    var usercodeIn = document.getElementById("Usercode").value;
    var passwordIn = document.getElementById("Password").value;

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(User){ 
    
      if(User != 'FALSE')  // Found User
      {
       document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "welcome " + User ;

       google.script.run.LoadTable(usercodeIn) ;

      }
      else if(User == 'FALSE') //Not Found User
      {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Wrong Password!";     
      }    
    }).checkLogin(usercodeIn,passwordIn);

    }

</script>
```

After Login successful I try to run Loadtable(usercode) to render Table.html with data base on usercode but It only login and show success prompt , but not render Table.html

This is sound pretty easy, but I really don't know what to do ,So please help Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Provided there are no Date objects in `argsObject` you could simply do `tmp.argsObject = argsObject`.

**Code.gs**

```
function render(file,argsObject){

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
  if(argsObject){
    tmp.argsObject = argsObject.
  } 
  return    tmp.evaluate() ;
}
```

**Then in your templeted HTML.**

```
<table>
  <? for (let i = 0; i < argsObject.array.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr><td><?= argsObject.array[i] ?></td></tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

**Reference**

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I still not understand the concept.
So my question is 
Should I render "Table" in  Javascript (by using google.script.run.LoadTable(usercodeIn)  which still not working right now ? or Should I do in much proper way ? please advice ,Thank you

Comment: I have revised my answer to give more detail as to how it is done.

Comment: Now I can show data on Table .Thank you so much. but I still cannot open Table.html after getUser , Please advice

Comment: I don't see `getUser` in your scripts.

Comment: I mean after .checklogin and get user information from firebase . I would like to pass user information to get specific data from spreadsheet which belong to user that login .

Comment: I don't see `checkLogin` either.  Are you sure its working?  You could use a `withFailureHandler` to confirm.  For me I'm not sure where it is failing.